# Get Google Streetview heading by PHP

Tags: php, curl, geocoding, google-maps-static-api

Good day, I am trying to setup a Streetview Static API in PHP.
I got as far that I got the address to coords by GeoCode.

I got the image of the address to show.
The last part however is still puzzling me. Thats the heading.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=800x800&location=%2052.525113,%205.487970&fov=90&heading=0&pitch=0&key=*GOOGLE_API_KEY*
```

I can find a lot of explanations about obtaining the heading by Javascript. But none in the form of a PHP solution.

It almost feels like it is impossible.

But if there'd only be a way to calculate the exact heading : `&heading=0` of the building it would be solved. But are there any specific google API calls required?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to get the heading from the query parameter?

Comment: Well if there's any query I could do that would be great. But I have no clue to what endpoint and what parameters to set.